# react-router v4 + electron - Does a timeline exist where they play nice together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router, electron

I'm trying to use react-router v4 inside an electron app.

Issue number one: electron loads the initial page as `file:///path/to/project/index.html`, react-router expects the initial page to be "/" and as such doesn't match it and renders nothing.

My initial solution to this was this little nasty piece of code to redirect to the right page on app start:

```
{window.location.href.endsWith('index.html') && <Redirect to="/" />}
```

This works perfectly until webpack-dev-server pops up to ruin the party - as soon as I make a single change to the code and webpack reloads the page to show the latest changes, it tries to load the new `file:///` route, erroring out and showing a blank page.

Anyone ever dealt with this? Are we just doomed to  an endless loop of manual electron restarting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone ever stumbles upon this, I "solved" the issue using MemoryRouter instead.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the wrong link between the build folder & entry point of your app...

Try the following ways, it will definitely solve your error

DON’T USE in this way

```
win.loadURL(isDev ? ‘http://localhost:3000' : file://${path.join(__dirname, ‘../build/index.html’)});
```

USE IN THIS WAY

```
win.loadURL(isDev ? ‘http://localhost:3000' : file://${__dirname}/../build/index.html);
```

and if you use React router you must replace **BrowserRouter** with **HashRouter**